# Applying a function to a number of variables stored as a list

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

If I have a function of several variables $f(a,b,...)$, where the variables are stored in a list

```
{a,b,...}
```

how do I call on the function? The following:

```
f[{a,b,...}]
```

tries to apply the function to the list as a whole, whereas I want

```
f[a,b,...]
```

What is the quick way of doing this (I have a lot of variables, so don't want to write them all out every time I want $f$)? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `list = {a, b, c};
f @@ list`

Comment: That's what [`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) does. Or the shorthand, which is `@@`.